# React: Why is my child component updating the state of its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just making a simple form component that reads in the user information and displays it in the form as values. After being edited the change can be saved or canceled. However the local state updates it's parent state which has got me scratching my head.

I have a parent component with a user info object inside its state object:

```
 usrInfo: {
    userName: {name: 'usrname', title: "User Name", value: 'state.user'}, 
    firstName: {name: 'fname', title: "First Name", value: "asdf"},  
    lastName: {name: 'lname',  title: "Last Name", value: "asdf"}, 
    title: {name: 'title', title: "Title", value: "asdf" }, 
    email: {name: 'email',title: "E-mail",value: "asdf@asdf.com"}
  },
```

my child component displays this state no problem. An edit button is clicked in the child and calls a function also in the child to set the userCashe child state to it's parrent user state:

```
  casheState() {;
    this.setState((prevState, props) => { 
        return {userInfoCashe: props.user };
    })
  }
```

then a form populates with the userInfoCash as values and when edited it updates the child state:

```
  changeHandler = (event) => {
    let usrCopy = {...this.state.userInfoCashe};
    usrCopy[event.target.id].value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({userInfoCashe: usrCopy});

    console.log(this.state.userInfoCashe[event.target.id].value)
    console.log(this.props.user[event.target.id].value)
            // ^^ these are the same, why?
  };
```

this function mutates it's parent user state. HOW AND WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?! I thought that react was built on one-way data binding.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a code sandbox with the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/ql80x5z95w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I would like to suggest to use lodash npm it will support javascript functions

reference link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

install lodash : npm install --save lodash

after installing it import it in your file wherever you want to use

```
    import _ from "lodash";


    changeHandler = (event) => {
    let usrCopy = _.cloneDeep(...this.state.userInfoCashe);

    usrCopy[event.target.id].value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({userInfoCashe: usrCopy});

    console.log(this.state.userInfoCashe[event.target.id].value)
    console.log(this.props.user[event.target.id].value)
            // ^^ these are the same, why?
  };
```

please try this, it will not update you original state it will update only the where took the copy of state.

Comment: I might end up going with this because of time but I'd hate to install a package just to get react to do what it's supposed to do out of the box. Thanks!

Comment: My question remains about why, but this did solve the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState` doesn't update the state immediately. Its [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). So if your console.log shows the same state before and after, then its because of this only.
You can try doing something like this :

```
this.setState({userInfoCashe: usrCopy}, ()=> {console.log(this.state.userInfoCashe);})
```

to actually see if your state got mutated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will add that to my toolkit. I had tested that another way and yes it's still mutated